# Vue lazyloading, remove spinner when image loads

Tags: css, image, vue.js, lazy-loading, nuxt.js

I have a vue Nuxt project where I explore lazyloading with [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) package.

I created a **spinner** component (html css only) who should be visible only while the image is loading.

I also created an **ImageItem** component who includes the spinner component and it looks like this:

```js
< script >
  import spinner from '~/components/spinner.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    spinner,
  },
  props: {
    source: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
  },
} <
/script>
```

```css
<style lang="scss" scoped>.imageItem {
  position: relative;
  .image {
    z-index: 2;
    &.lazyload,
    &.lazyloading {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    &.lazyloaded {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 1s linear 0.35s;
    }
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<template>
 <div class="imageItem">
  <spinner />
  <img class="image lazyload" :data-srcset="source" />
 </div>
</template>
```

To explain my code, I have props: **source** where In parent component i pass the image i want to lazyload. Also in the CSS while the image is loading, the image has **.lazyloading** class and when is loaded **.lazyloaded** class. Right now when Image is loaded i put it on top of the spinner.

My problem is, when I load the image I want to hide or destroy the spinner element since I think just putting the image on top is not the best way to do it. Can someone give me direction how should I properly hide the spinner when the image is loaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lazysizes` fires an event when loading the image is finished : `lazyloaded` event, So you can do this :

```
<template>
    <div class="imageItem">
        <spinner v-if="lazyloading"/>
        <img class="image lazyload" :data-srcset="source" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import spinner from '~/components/spinner.vue'

export default {
    data(){
        return {
           lazyloading
        }
    },
    mounted(){
       document.addEventListener('lazyloaded', (e) => {
              this.lazyloading = false;
          }
       });
   }

}
</script>
```

Comment: I was not aware of this, but this should work, thank you.
In the meanwhile i discovered on load directive for vue, where I can see when the image is loaded so i can hide the spinner.

Comment: @martcube - would be great to see this solution too

Comment: I still recommend  the above example since you work with an event from lazysizes it self.
the othey way is using load event in vue, however I could not find any documentation about it to share with you. a simple example will be like this.

`<spinner v-if="lazyloading"/>
<img @load="lazyloading=false" />`